# How does C# iterate through Form Controls in a Foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

As in the title, my question is how does C# iterate through form controls in a `foreach` loop? In case that is a bit too vague I'll add a bit more detail:

When I do `foreach(Control c in MyForm)` how does it index(?) through the controls? Is it based on tab order or something else? Any assistance would be appreciated as I'm trying to find out if I can place values into an array in a neater and more organized fashion.

Comment: This isn't a C# question, it's a .NET Windows Forms implementation question. It depends on the implementation. Try looking for the source code for Form.cs and see how it's implemented. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/

Comment: I believe there actually are `GetChildIndex(control)` and `SetCHildIndex(control)` methods that can be used.

Comment: I think you're asking about `TabIndex`, possibly... if I'm _reading between the keypresses_, and since you explicitly mentioned "tab order."  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't return controls based on tab index, it returns the controls in the order you added them the `Controls` collection.

You can see this order in designer in *Document Outline* window. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and change the order by moving controls in tree in the *Document Outline* window. Also if you use `Bring To front` and `Send To back` toolbar buttons you can change this order in design time.

At run-time you can change this order by calling `SendToBack` and `BringToFront` method of controls or `SetChildIndex` method of `Controls` collection.

To get the index of a control, you can use `GetChildIndex` method of `Controls` collection.

Also keep in mind `foreach(Control c in this.Controls)` just will scan controls which you put directly on the form. For example if you have a panel on form and the panel contains some controls, children of panel are in `panel.Controls` collection and not in controls collection of form.

Comment: Didn't know that changing z-order actually modified the underlying collection. One more reason to avoid iterating that collection and depending on order!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Im going to try out the document outline method and see if that solves my conundrum. Additionally thanks for the additional bit on panels and the like. The section im looping through is inside a panel so in my overall method I'm passing in that panel, but when i go to validate my full form it will be good to know that i have to put each panel through the method. Thank you for your assistance =)

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your assistance :)

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` always works the same, so doing it over a form's controls doesn't change anything.

It doesn't really use an index either; `foreach` only works on instances of classes that implement `IEnumerable` which means they have a `GetEnumerator` method. `foreach` uses the returned `IEnumerator` to go through the collection one at a time; order is dependent on the actual implementation.

For `List` (or any array) this is in-order (ie index 0 is first, 1 second, and so on); for a random implementation of `IEnumerable` you would have to look at the source. In your specific example, look at the type of the `Controls` collection on `Form`. Its a `ControlCollection` so you'll want to look on [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) to find how it enumerates.

Based on the [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/1ac71dc0d6ce7f92.html)  it appears to be in-order with some safeguards against controls being removed during enumeration.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed and quick response. I will definitely try to take a look at the Reference Source. Thanks again kind sir.=)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the order that the controls are iterated over? I want to say that the controls are iterated over in the order that they were added to the Form's control collection. You can check this in the `InitializeComponents` designer method to see the order the controls are listed in that method.

Comment: Or see the order in *Document Outline* window.